# How do I use input from user to close or continue a while loop

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am tryin to make a program that solves this. I can't seem to get the part where if the user wants to order more, he say yes, and the loop continues.

The user is first asked to choose between 3 different types of pizzas (margherita: 15.5SGD, marinara: 17.5SGD and napoletana: 18SGD).
Once the pizza type is selected, he is invited to type the amount of such pizzas he would like to order.

Finally, the user is asked if he would like to stop the ordering.
If not, then the menu comes back to asking to select the pizza type again.
If yes, the final price is printed according to the pizzas ordered and the program stops.

Here's what I got so far

```
margherita_P= 15.5
marinara_P= 17.5
napoletana_P= 18

Pizza_Option = input("key in type of pizza wanted: ")
Pizza_Amt = int(input("amt of pizza wanted: "))
x = 1
price = 0

while x == 1:
    if Pizza_Option == 'margherita':
        price += margherita_P * Pizza_Amt
        print(price, " SGD")

    elif Pizza_Option == 'marinara':
        price += marinara_P * Pizza_Amt
        print(price, " SGD")

    elif Pizza_Option == 'napoletana':
        price += napoletana_P * Pizza_Amt
        print(price, " SGD")

    else:
        print("error")

y= input("type yes if you want more: ")
if y != 'yes':
    x +=1
```

Comment: you need another while loop

Comment: wrapping the wholle thing

Comment: @ChristianSloper I'm really new to python, so I'm sorry if I don't get it. I tried this, and it was pretty much the same. Could you show me what exactly I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you are in an infinite loop because the lines where you would get out of it, are not actually in the loop. These lines have to be indented.
Also, you have to put the input of the type and amount into the loop.

```
margherita_P = 15.5
marinara_P = 17.5
napoletana_P = 18

x = 1
price = 0

while x == 1:
    Pizza_Option = input("key in type of pizza wanted: ")
    Pizza_Amt = int(input("amt of pizza wanted: "))
    
    if Pizza_Option == 'margherita':
        price += margherita_P * Pizza_Amt
        print(price, " SGD")

    elif Pizza_Option == 'marinara':
        price += marinara_P * Pizza_Amt
        print(price, " SGD")

    elif Pizza_Option == 'napoletana':
        price += napoletana_P * Pizza_Amt
        print(price, " SGD")

    else:
        print("error")

    y = input("type yes if you want more: ")
    if y != 'yes':
        x += 1
```

Comment: right ok, I see why the infinite loop kept happening. I get it! thank you so much :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap user input section to the `while` loop and exit the loop when users say no. Here is my suggestion:

```
margherita_P = 15.5
marinara_P = 17.5
napoletana_P = 18

total_price = 0

while True:
    Pizza_Option = input("key in type of pizza wanted: ")
    Pizza_Amt = int(input("amt of pizza wanted: "))

    if Pizza_Option == 'margherita':
        price = margherita_P * Pizza_Amt
        total_price += price
        print(price, " SGD")

    elif Pizza_Option == 'marinara':
        price = marinara_P * Pizza_Amt
        total_price += price
        print(price, " SGD")

    elif Pizza_Option == 'napoletana':
        price = napoletana_P * Pizza_Amt
        total_price += price
        print(price, " SGD")

    else:
        print("error")

    y = input("type yes if you want more: ")
    if y != 'yes':
        break

print("Total price: ", total_price)
```

Output:

```
key in type of pizza wanted: margherita
amt of pizza wanted: 3
46.5  SGD
type yes if you want more: yes
key in type of pizza wanted: napoletana
amt of pizza wanted: 5
90  SGD
type yes if you want more: no
Total price:  136.5
```